# Test script for SQL Server 2008 compatibility on a SQL 2012 server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to test a script for compatibility with older versions of a SQL Server on a newer version?

To somehow tell the server not to understand all the new features (new function names, new syntactic sugar etc.)

That way we could do away with VMs hosting older SQL server versions and free up precious resources on our testbed VM host.

Comment: you can set comparability mode to a lower version from within SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping an old server version alive, you can create a database for testing on your main (current) server and then set the compatibility of that database to a lower version.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100    -- 100 = Engine v10.x = SQL 2008
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

Possibly even simpler would be to Detach the lower-level database from the old server, copy the related files (MDF+LDF) over to the new server and then Attach it there. Doing so will usually not change the compatibility level, unless it is such an old level that the new server does not support it anymore.

Comment: Note Not all features that vary by compatibility level are supported on SQL Database. From the above MS article.

Comment: I have tried to run a known erroneous script on such a database. The line `ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET RECOVERY SIMPLE` throws syntax errors on our 2008R2 server ("Syntax error at or near CURRENT"), but it did work on said compatible database.

Comment: Ok, that could be problematic, but if there are just a few such problems then there are probably SQL workarounds. E.g. `EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE ' + @dbName + ' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'`) may work in this case.

Comment: I think that the detach/attach process is a bit overkill, just making a full backup and restoring it in the new server will get you an exact copy of the DB, including compatibility level (supposing that the old version compat level is still supported in the new version, as @Serg points, if not the backup will fail with 'not supported')

Comment: You don't need `CURRENT` for the current DB, just use `ALTER DATABASE SET RECOVERY SIMPLE`.

Comment: Let's highlight the important bit in the documentation link posted by Peter. **Compatibility level provides only partial backward compatibility...**   So the short answer is NO. Nor is it intended for use in production databases.